# Rankx by year in Power BI Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, ranking, daxstudio

For each couple year-month I need to create the ranking of my average revenue. So far this is what I have been able to reach:

[image]

However, what I need to do is to re-start the ranking when the year changes. But righ now is a consecutive ranking, it does not consider the year, just the value.

I tried another metric definition using some indications but the result was always 1:

```
Monthly Rank by Year = 
VAR current_year = SELECTEDVALUE(DateDim[Year])
VAR tmp = FILTER(ALL(DateDim), DateDim[Year] = current_year)
RETURN 
RANKX(tmp, [Monthly Average Revenue],,DESC, Dense)
```

How can I fix this calculation.

Answer (score 0):

First write a measure

```
MVR = SUM(Data[Monthly Average Revenue])
```

Then write Rank measure

```
Rank = RANKX(ALLEXCEPT(Data, Data[Year]), [MVR], , DESC, Dense)
```

[image]